# Given square real matrix $A$ with $\det(A) = 108$ and $(A-2I)(A^2-9I)=0$, is $A$ normal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

> Given real square matrix $A$ with $\det (A) = 108$ and $(A-2I)(A^2-9I) = 0$, find:
>
> a. The characteristic and minimal polynomial options (all options).
>
> b. Is $A$ normal?

I think I found the minimal and characteristic polynomials but I can't tell if $A$ is normal.

Comment: What are the polynomials you have found?

Comment: @uniquesolution $(t-2)^4(t-3)^2(t+3)$ and $(t-2)(t-3)(t+3)$

Comment: Are you assuming that $A$ is a $7\times 7$ matrix?

Comment: Thats the only way the constant matches the determinant I think

Comment: I don't understand. Is the matrix being $7\times 7$ part of the assumptions of the question or not? Without specifying the order of the matrix, your question makes little sense.

Comment: Part of the original question is "find the dimension n". We know the constant of thr charictarstic polynomial is 108 and that the given polynomial divides it. So that's what I came up with. Not 100% sure of course

Comment: @Jason, I thought I made some silly mistake and deleted the comment, but actually I think it's fine. Let me repost it.

Comment: @ennar ive updated the question to emphasize that it means all options for Charictaristic and min polynomials

Comment: Determinant is product of eigenvalues and $108 = 2^2\cdot 3^3$. Since polynomial $(x-2)(x-3)(x+3)$ vanishes at $A$, we know that $\sigma(A)\subseteq\{2,3,-3\}$, thus possible characteristic polynomials are $(x-2)^2(x-3)^3$ and $(x-2)^2(x-3)(x+3)^2$ with corresponding minimal polynomials $(x-2)(x-3)$ and $(x-2)(x-3)(x+3)$.

Comment: Yea my bad i meant 2 not 4, and the rest makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Normal matrix with real eigenvalues is Hermitian which in real case just means symmetric. From the minimal polynomial you know how Jordan normal form looks like. Can you find non-symmetric matrix with such a Jordan normal form?

Comment: Yea I can by multiplying with a non orthogonal invertable matrix. Thanks